# Sull'uso della locuzione avverbiale "in solitaria"

Tags: word-usage

Qualche giorno fa, mentre ascoltavo il telegiornale di Euronews, ho sentito questa frase:

> L'attentatore ha agito *in solitaria*.

Sono stata stupita dall'espressione "in solitaria": conoscevo "in solitario" come locuzione avverbiale, ma non "in solitaria".

Ho cercato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/solitario/) e ho trovato "in solitario" come locuzione avverbiale

> come locuz. agg. e avv., *in solitario* (*una regata, una traversata transatlantica in solitario*)

ma non menziona niente su "in solitaria" come locuzione avverbiale. Cercando su Google però si trovano alcuni esempi di uso di questa locuzione. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: "in solitaria" si usa nello stesso modo di "in solitario"? Tutte e due queste locuzioni si usano per uguale o una è più frequente dell'altra?

Answer (score 4):

Il Devoto-Oli 2007, alla voce ***solitario***, scrive:

> - loc. in s[olitario], in assoluta solitudine: crociera, navigazione in s.; scalata in s. (o la solitaria s.f.).

Scorrendo Ngram si può notare che l'espressione *in solitaria* è abbastanza diffusa, in particolare in riferimento ad imprese (spesso sportive)  difficili e pericolose. La locuzione sembra fare riferimento appunto  ad un "impresa" solitaria. Si tratta  di un uso al femminile di "in solitario".

> - ... successivamente, tra il 1991 e il 1997, sono nate l'Associazione Surfisti Italiani (ASI) e la Federazione Italiana Surfing (FISURF), che sono entrambe al di fuori del sistema C.O.N.I. (15) ***Le regate transoceaniche in solitaria*** sono divenute oggi  ... [*Sport estremi e responsabilità*
>     di Laura Santoro](https://books.google.it/books?id=1ZMI6c84nUEC&pg=PA85&dq=%22in%20solitaria%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=NvOPVeK8JoyR7Aaki7nQCg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20solitaria%22&f=false)
> - ... in Italia, a un raduno di alpinisti di livello internazionale che avevano ***scalato l'Eigerwand in solitaria***, d'inverno. Incredibile! E lì, in una diapositiva, c'era l' ottantaseienne Fritz Wiesner che faceva un passaggio di 5.11 (una difficoltà 116  ... [*Parlino le montagne, scorrano i fiumi* di David R. Brower, Steve Chapple](https://books.google.it/books?id=XWQB_5WA-tkC&pg=PT68&dq=%22in%20solitaria%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=NvOPVeK8JoyR7Aaki7nQCg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22in%20solitaria%22&f=false)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20solitaria&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20solitaria%3B%2Cc0) in solitaria

Comment: Se ho capito bene, il Devoto-Oli, come il Treccani, menziona "in solitario" ma non "in solitaria".

Comment: In alcuni degli esempi di Ngram, "solitaria" ha la funzione di aggettivo.

Comment: Negli esempi che ti ho proposto "in solitaria" è una locuzione avverbiale, 'solitaria' è comunque un aggettivo comune. Nei dizionari in effetti non viene citata chiaramente come esempio di locuzione avverbiale, ma di fatto è usata in alternativa a "in solitario".

Comment: @Charo Aggiungerei all'ultimo commento di Josh61 che "in solitaria" in certi contesti è molto più comune, almeno negli ultimi anni. Ad esempio non mi ricordo di aver mai sentito dire di "una traversata dell'atlantico in solitario", ma sempre "in solitaria". In altra parole, anche se si tratterebbe di una locuzione avverbiale, nell'uso si tende a declinare l'aggettivo in modo che concordi con il sostantivo: traversata->solitaria.

Comment: @Charo Per strano che possa sembrare, nell'uso che ne sento fare, viene usata l'espressione "in solitaria" anche in riferimento a sostantivi maschili: "ho fatto un viaggio attraverso l'India in solitaria". Suppongo perché l'uso più comune è in riferimento a sostantivi come "scalata" o "traversata" e per estensione la locuzione standard è diventata "in solitaria" invece che "in solitario" (ipotesi mia, tutta da avvalorare).